# How to bring the Android emulator to the front from the command line

Tags: android, bash, android-emulator

I found a command to start the emulator from the command line:

```
$ android-sdk-path/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26 -netdelay none -netspeed full
```

but I need to check from command line if the emulator is already running then just bring it to the front of the screen. Is this possible from the command line?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you can use this command to check if the emulator with the mentioned name is running or not `ps aux | grep -i emulator | grep -i Nexus_5X_API_26 | wc -l | read test | if [ "$test" != "0" ]; then; echo "yup"; fi;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to automatically show the emulator (bring it to foreground) after installing an apk from command line.

Comment: bringing the emulator to the front of the screen will require you to use Applescript if OSX or wmctrl if Linux, you can find examples online. The emulator itself doesn't have a command to do that internally as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer to my question:

Create a osscript file `showEmulator.scpt`

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application process "Dock"
    tell list 1
      tell UI element "emulator"
        perform action "AXPress"
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
end tell
```

and then execute it from terminal on this way
 `osascript ~/scripts/showEmulator.scpt`

Comment: Can you link to a source, where you've found this information?

Comment: On Mojave and later you'll also need to add your app to Accessibility so that it is allowed assistive access.